# How to Turn off - VS CODE Opening all the internal classes it encounters during java debugging such as printstream class , String class

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using VS CODE to learn java. While debugging , it opens all the internal classes it encounters in the code.

For example:-

```
class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x= 7;
        int y = 8;
        System.out.println("Hello World"); // opens prints stream class and executes each line per click of this print stream class
        int z = x+y;
    }
}
```

What I want - when the debugger hits  `System.out.println("hello world");` it prints `hello world` and moves on rather than opening the printstream class.

Pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google stepFilter vscode and use it.